# how to slide the divs in section from bottom to top

Tags: jquery

I would be  thankful if any one can help me in creating div sliding from bottom to top one by one using jquery. first div should be active for some time and slowly move up and the second div should start coming up and stay for a while and this should continue with all the divs.

```
#carousel {
height:300px;
overflow:hidden;
}

#carousel div {
width:500px;
border:1px solid #ccc;
height:300px;
position:relative;
}

#carousel div:first-child {
background-color:#e01783;
}

#carousel div:nth-child(2) {
background-color:#ff4e00;
}

#carousel div:nth-child(3) {
background-color:#ffd141;
}

#carousel div:nth-child(4) {
background-color:#6dcb99;
}

#carousel div:last-child {
background-color:#e2b87f;
}


<section id="carousel">
                               <div></div>
                               <div></div>
                               <div></div>
                               <div></div>
                               <div></div>
               </section>




 var t = setInterval(function(){

        $("#carousel div").animate({marginTop:300},5000,function(){

            $(this).find("div:last").after($(this).find("div:first"));
            $(this).css({marginTop:0});

              });
    },5000);
```

Comment: I just boost up him to try more by himself. @webeno

Comment: please find my jquery code which i was trying..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try the following (I used jquery 1.8.3)

```
$('#carousel div:first-child').delay( 800 ).slideUp( 300 );
$('#carousel div:nth-child(2)').delay( 1600 ).slideUp( 300 );
$('#carousel div:nth-child(3)').delay( 2400 ).slideUp( 300 );
$('#carousel div:nth-child(4)').delay( 3200 ).slideUp( 300 );
$('#carousel div:last-child').delay( 4000 ).slideUp( 300 );
```

**[DEMO HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/8H4Bm/1/)**

Or even better...

```
var delayMe = 0;
$('#carousel div').siblings().each( function() {
    delayMe += 800;
    $(this).delay(delayMe).slideUp(300);
});
```

**[UPDATED DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/Fchs6/2/)**

Comment: what do you think about mine? if it works for you, feel free to select my answer as best (big green check mark), thanks!

Comment: You could use `slideDown` instead of `slideUp` if you needed the divs to go down rather, also you could set the time to something larger for slower animation, like `slideDown(1000)`

Comment: sorry...i dint know that i have to make the check mark green...this is the first time i am posting